# Creating additional attributes for regional intersections?

Tags: polygon, attribute-table, redistricting

A certain country is (simultaneously and independently) divided into 400 regions and 100 judicial districts. Each division is represented by a separate multipolygon layers with units as features. Intuitively one judicial district may contain many regions. However, one region can belong to many judicial districts (eg. Northern part of the region R_1 can belong to the district D_1 but its southern part can belong to the district D_2) - the aim of this is to reduce the risk of collusion between local judges and authorities.

I would like to create a database describing the relations between regions and districts. In the “districts” layer I’d like to create 400 columns/attributes representing all regions. The values of the attributes should be binary i.e. “1” if a given region overlaps/intersects with a given district and “0” if it does not.

For instance, for the district D_37 I would like to have “O” value of the attribute R_123 because the “region 123” does not overlap with the district 37 and “1” for the attribute R_44 because the “region 44” does actually overlap with the district 37.

How I should do this to avoid unnecessary difficulties (I use QGIS)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using?